# Facebook request dialog with custom message notification

Tags: facebook

I have a very simple use case. My app lets users send invitations to his friends, say for a birthday party. Friends then accept the invitation(and app).

I am using RequestDialog to send notifications to multiple users. Notification was sent successfully but the message is confusing to the user as it says

"User A Invited you to try APPNAME. Try Now".

Is there a way to customize this message? It should something like

"User A Invited you to his birthday party using APPNAME. Accept it now"

I believe I cannot use app generated requests as invitees hasn't authorized the app yet.

Any other ideas or workarounds to send notification, message with a link so users can click on it and accept the app and thus accept the birthday invitation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I memory serves, Facebook used to let you customize (many years ago), but, probably due to abuse, they no longer allow you to customize what the invitee sees.  It's all standard.  However, when the user comes to your app to authenticate, you can customize the Enhanced Auth dialog to your content.

Answer (score 2):

You should use `message` parameter of [Requests Dialog](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/)

> `message` - The Request string the receiving user will see. It appears as a question posed by the sending user. The maximum length is 255 characters. The message value is not displayed in Notifications and can only be viewed on the Apps and Games Dashboard. Invites (requests where the recipient has not installed the app) do not display this value.

Comment: Message is displayed while selecting the user. Sorry if I wasn't clear  but I am talking about the notification that friends receive in facebook.

Comment: I don't believe you can customize the message that appears in the *actual* notification. It will generally say, "USER sent you a request in APP."

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a way to customize invite messages, and interestingly, to Usman Ashraf's point, as far as I can tell BranchOut can't do this anymore either (or at least I can't replicate it with their app).  If anybody else can replicate it, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

What you might want to do would be to allow

```
    new_style_message: true,
```

Under your

```
FB.ui({
    method: 'apprequests',
    new_style_message: true,
    message: "is bringing you to the UPicnic !",
    display: "iframe"
},somefunction);
```

What this does is when the notification is sent to the user(s) , it will show up as the message instead. Not much customization but that's the least I can find.